# shell script replace , with ','

Tags: bash, shell, replace

I'm relatively new to shell scripting. This would be very easy for me to do in PHP, but I'm not sure the syntax in shell.

I'm running a query (assigned to a variable) that brings back a comma separated value with spaces to designate a new row.

Example output of the query:

```
04/2014,Linux,24124 04/2014,Solaris,24509 04/2014,Windows,40824
```

As you can see, the results come back comma seperated, with a single space in between rows. I'm looping through this and am able to split them at the space.

```
array=(${COUNT// / })
for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(ID,LATEST_SCAN_TIME,OPERATING_SYSTEM,COUNT) VALUES ('','${array[i]}');
done
```

For some reason I'm having trouble replacing the "," in ${array[i]} to "','".

Current output:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE (ID,LATEST_SCAN_TIME,OPERATING_SYSTEM,COUNT) VALUES ('','04/2014,Linux,24124');
```

What I would like:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE (ID,LATEST_SCAN_TIME,OPERATING_SYSTEM,COUNT) VALUES ('','04/2014','Linux','24124');
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```
kent$  echo "a,b,c"|awk -F, -v OFS="','" -v q="'" '{$1=$1}$0=q$0q' 
'a','b','c'
```

or

```
kent$  echo "a,b,c"|sed -r "s/^|$/'/g;s/,/','/g"
'a','b','c'
```

Comment: I'm running into issues with these. Could you show me how to use either of these commands incorporating the example I gave (insert statement)? Thanks!